# Draw multiple tables in a plot using vba in excel

Tags: vba, excel, plot

I am a beginner coder for excel as you will see. I am trying to make line graphs in excel that each graph would have multiple series in them.

For example, the first graph needs to be labeled "Voltages" and it needs to have the data under the columns names Voltages in the second row.

The number of graphs depends on the number of the battery monitors which in this case I have 4.

I am very sorry, I don't know how to upload a file here. But the tables that have data are separated by 10 columns so they aren't right next to one another.

```
Sub test()

Dim Chart1 As ChartObject

Set Chart1 = Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects.Add(52, 0, 1000, 500)
With Chart1.Chart
    .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H3:H2502")
    .ChartWizard Title:="Voltage", HasLegend:=True, CategoryTitle:="Time (s)", ValueTitle:="Voltage", Gallery:=xlLineStacked

    '.Legend = "Battery 1"        This does not work

End With

End Sub
```

How can I control the legend text?
How can I add another set of data to this graph?

Thank you so much for your time

Comment: can you describe your sheet in more detail? Is `H3:H2502` your battery 1 data? will battery 2 data be `I3:I2502`? Where will the other 3 charts go? Or do you mean all 4 batteries will be on the same chart?

Comment: My apologies for not being clear. I just figured out how to add the other tables

'.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(2).Values = Sheets("Sheet1").Range'

However, I yet do not know how to change the legend text

Comment: @Vik: if you show the screen shot  , your problem solved more fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.SeriesCollection(n).name is item of legend.

```
Sub test()

    Dim Chart1 As ChartObject
    Dim Cht As Chart
    Dim n As Integer

    Set Chart1 = Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects.Add(52, 0, 1000, 500)
    Set Cht = Chart1.Chart

    With Cht
          .HasTitle = True
         .ChartType = xlLineStacked
         .Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionRight
         With .ChartTitle
             .Characters.Text = "Voltage"
             .Characters.Font.Size = 12
         End With

         .SeriesCollection.NewSeries 'Add series
         n = n + 1
         With .SeriesCollection(n)
             .Name = "Battery 1"
             .XValues = Range("a1:f1")
             .Values = Range("a2:f2")
          End With
         .SeriesCollection.NewSeries 'Add series
         n = n + 1
         With .SeriesCollection(n)
             .Name = "Battery 2"
             .XValues = Range("a1:f1")
             .Values = Range("a3:f3")
         End With
         .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
         .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Votage"
         .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
         .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Time (s)"
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much Dy.Lee. You have done a great job. Cheers